# How to create and release a TImage control at runtime on Android platform?

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-xe7

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  imageIndex := 0;
end;
```

In Delphi XE7, I'm creating a `TImage` control at runtime this way (called from a button click event):

```
newImage := TImage.Create(Self);
Inc(imageIndex);
newImage.Tag := imageIndex;
newImage.Name := 'Image' + IntToStr(imageIndex);
newImage.Padding.Right := 20;
newImage.Parent := HorzScrollBox2;
newImage.Visible := True;
newImage.Bitmap.LoadFromFile(TPath.Combine(TPath.GetDocumentsPath, 'test.jpg'));
newImage.Align := TAlignLayout.Left;
newImage.Width := 200;
newImage.OnGesture := OwnImageGesture;
newImage.touch.InteractiveGestures := [TInteractiveGesture.LongTap];
newImage.PopupMenu := pmIgame;
```

This is how I free a `TImage` object (called from a button click event):

```
FindComponent('Image1').Free;
```

When I run under Windows and create an object and free it, it works well. But when I run under Android device or emulator the `TImage` object is not released. I don't know why.

Comment: It would be so much cleaner to use arrays rather than `FindComponent`. I guess the answer to your question is to call `DisposeOf` rather than `Free`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to free a component in Android / iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27818697/how-to-free-a-component-in-android-ios)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I know this is a very old question, but when you say array, do you mean array of TImage objects.

Comment: @ThN Yes that's precisely it